# dj-rest-auth overriding reset password default email template not working

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-allauth, dj-rest-auth

I wanna override the default email that gets sent to the user when he forgets his password
here is the implementation:

```
#urls.py

    path('dj-rest-auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')),
    path('dj-rest-auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path("password-reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/",TemplateView.as_view(
        template_name="main/password_reset_confirm.html"),name='password_reset_confirm'),
```

```
#serializers.py


class CustomPasswordResetSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):
    
    def get_email_options(self):
        return {
            'html_email_template_name': 'custom_email_template.html',
        }    

    def validate_email(self, value):
        self.reset_form = self.password_reset_form_class(data=self.initial_data)
        if not self.reset_form.is_valid():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(self.reset_form.errors)
        elif not User.objects.filter(email=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("A user with this email already exists!")
        return value
```

```
# settings.py

REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER': 'main.serializers.UserSerializer',
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER': 'main.serializers.CustomPasswordResetSerializer'
}

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS':  [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I tried the solutions from many stackoverflow questions and github issues none of them was working
Other than overriding the get_email_options method i tried overriding the save method like so:

```
    def save(self):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        opts = {
            'use_https': request.is_secure(),
            'from_email': getattr(settings, 'DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL'),
            'html_email_template_name': 'custom_email_template.html',
            'request': request,
        }
        self.reset_form.save(**opts)
```

and it did not work , i tried putting it under

```
-templates
   -registration
       password_reset_email.html
```

and it still did not work.
note that i have the template in the following location while trying the above solutions:

```
templates
      custom_email_template.html
```